# Is it possible to use three screens with Intel HD 3000 integrated graphics?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

I'm getting a new Lenovo T520 with Intel integrated graphics.

Is it possible to use three screens with Intel HD 3000 (the laptop internal screen + two external screens)?

Comment: Does the T520 come with two external monitor ports?

Comment: @techie007: Yes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, according to [Intel's FAQ](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-031040.htm) on the HD 3000 integrated graphics:

> No. Intel® graphics products can output to one or two display devices
>   at the same time. More than two display devices can be physically
>   connected, but only two display devices can be used at any time.

However it seems you can use a splitter to "clone" a third monitor.

> Some customers report being able to use third-party video splitter
>   devices to allow output to more than two display devices. Intel has
>   not tested these configurations nor can make recommendations on these
>   third party devices.

Keep in mind cloning only mirrors exactly what is on one of the two monitors it will not be an independent third monitor.

Comment: This no longer appears to be the case. It looks like Intel has updated their drivers to support 3 displays.

Comment: @Tyler are you sure? any link?

Answer (score 2):

As already answered you just have 2 concurrent outputs. But you can split it (it's not mirroring).

So you take a big resolution (e.g. 3200x1200) and split it into two (e.g. 2x 1600x1200). You need to have these resolutions (there are some possibilities). I done it years ago with triple split (1 output to 3 monitors) for creating a cave with one graphics card.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running three displays on an HP EliteBook 8460P with Intel HD 3000 graphics adapter:

1. DVI port to HDMI Hanspree HF199H at 1440×900 (recommended). 
   1920×1080 works but overscans the physical screen.  That might be adjustable.
2. USB 3.0 port to Insignia USB to VGA to Dell S2330MX at 1360×768 (max that works)
3. Built in 14 inch display at 1366×768 (recommended)

I'm extending across the three displays – not mirroring.