# Hooking up a 3rd screen to mac mini (mid 2011)

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors, mac-mini

Ive got a mac mini setup via vga to run two screens, to do this ive got it setup as in the image bellow.

Im looking to add a 3rd screen but im not sure of the best way to do it.

I dont need audio out of any of the screens as that plays out of the mac mini.

i was also wandering the graphics card ive got - Intel HD Graphics 3000 processor with 384 MB of DDR3 SDRAM - will this be enough to handle 3 screens  ?

UPDATE: I have found i have a dual head to go [DualHead2Go Digital Edition](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/) lying around is there some way this could be incorporated to help.. ie. using one of the bellow ports as an input to the dual head and then outputting from there ?

[image: mac mini back]

Comment: Unfortunately with HD 3000, only two monitors are supported.   http://superuser.com/questions/350052/can-integrated-intel-hd-3000-graphics-be-used-for-triple-head

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, according to [Intel's FAQ](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-031040.htm) on the HD 3000 integrated graphics:

> No. Intel® graphics products can output to one or two display devices
>   at the same time. More than two display devices can be physically
>   connected, but only two display devices can be used at any time.

However it seems you can use a splitter to "clone" a third monitor.

> Some customers report being able to use third-party video splitter
>   devices to allow output to more than two display devices. Intel has
>   not tested these configurations nor can make recommendations on these
>   third party devices.

Keep in mind cloning only mirrors exactly what is on one of the two monitors it will not be an independent third monitor.

[Is it possible to use three screens with Intel HD 3000 integrated graphics?](https://superuser.com/questions/350052/can-integrated-intel-hd-3000-graphics-be-used-for-triple-head/350294#350294)

[This location says "No" as well.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9999/can-a-mac-mini-drive-three-monitors)

One thing that was brought up, however, was a USB video adapter.  [NewEgg](http://www.newegg.com/USB-Display-Adapters/SubCategory/ID-3046?Tid=19447&Tpk=usb%20video%20adapter) seems to have quite a [few](http://www.newegg.com/USB-Display-Adapters/SubCategory/ID-3046?Tid=19447&Tpk=usb%20video%20adapter) to choose from, but I cannot say whether they will work with Macs or not.

Comment: Thanks, i ended up purchasing an external usb video adapter, there not 100% the same as using just a dvi / hdmi as there is a slight lag in the connection between screen and machine, so any monitor running through one is a little slow, not unusable, but noticeable if your moving thing around quickly, fine for word ect, not so much for video

Answer (score 1):

Simply put: Replace one of the monitors by the DualHead2Go and connect that monitor and the third monitor to the DualHead2Go. This will work when the two monitors have the same resolution. The DualHead2Go looks for the resolution of the screens and tells the computer it's a screen with a resolution of twice the width of the monitors.

To your computer, this will just look like you have a really wide screen and work as long as the resolution of this virtual monitor doesn't exceed the abilities of your video card.