# 3 Monitors on Lenovo T420s - Intel HD Graphics 3000

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, vga, dvi

I have a Lenovo T420s with an Integrated Intel HD Graphics 3000 display adapter. The laptop is currently attached to a dock and the dock is connected to a monitor via DisplayPort and another via DVI.

I have looked up several ways online to add a 3rd monitor and they all say to enable Optimus in the BIOS but I do not have that option (probably because I have an integrated graphics adapter).

Would it be possible to add a 3rd monitor via:

1. VGA port on Dock or
2. VGA port on Laptop or
3. DisplayPort splitter on dock or
4. DisplayPort port on Laptop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can integrated Intel HD 3000 graphics be used for triple-head?](http://superuser.com/questions/350052/can-integrated-intel-hd-3000-graphics-be-used-for-triple-head)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to at least add the third monitor via either USB adapter (your choice as to what port it terminates to), or the Lenovo T420 series supports the ThinkVision external monitors (I have the 14" and love it!) - which takes a Y-Type USB-A to USB-Mini B. I am actually having issues going further than three monitors. I currently cannot activate the built-in display while all three monitors are plugged in.